# Hide databases from SQL Server with AG

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, security

I have 10 databases on a server. Each database is part of a different AG. Each database has its own listener. Can I hide all databases and show only the one database belonging to a listener? I also do not want to create a separate user for each listener as it will be a lot of users to be created and maintained across many database servers.

Comment: To understand what a listener is and why you see all databases (event the one does not belong to that Availability Group/Listener) see [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124947/availability-group-listener) question.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I hide all databases and show only the one database belonging to a listener?

Yes.  Have each AG's databases owned by a separate login created specifically for that purpose.

> I also do not want to create a separate user for each listener

Then no. There's no way to trim the list of databases a user can see based on the endpoint used to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: ok thanks. I thought so and now it is confirmed.